# JSPlumb Connect Tables Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I have 2 tables 5 rows of data in it and i want to connect each row of table_1 to table_2.
I can connect those 2 tables but not possible to connect each row of table_1 to table_2.

the code shown below:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
            <head>
                    <title>Example</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />    
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsplumb.org/js/1.3.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.1-all-min.js"></script>

            </head>
            <body >
            <div id="block1"  class ="node" style="position: absolute;">
                    <table id="table_1" style="border:2px solid #000;float:left;margin-right:9%;" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Drag Line 1<hr />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <div class ="class"><tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td -->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; family-font: Arial; color: red;">Name                      </td>
                </tr></div>                     
                <tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td-->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; color: red;">Age                                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td -->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; color: red;">DOB                       </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            <div  id="block2"  class ="node" style="position: absolute;">
                    <table id="table_2" style="border:2px solid #000;float:left;margin-right:9%;" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Drag Line 2<hr />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td -->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; family-font: Arial; color: red;">Name2                         </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td -->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; color: red;">Age2                      </td>
                </tr>
                <div class ="class"><tr>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td -->
                    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; color: red;">DOB2                      </td>
                </tr></div>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rowCount = $('#table_1 tr').length;
                    var sourceColor = "#000000";
                    var sourceOption = 
            {
                        anchor:"RightMiddle",
                            isSource:true,
                            isTarget:false,
                            endpoint:["Rectangle",{width:10, height:10}],
                            paintStyle:{fillStyle:"#66FF00"},
                maxConnections:-1
                }                                             
                    var targetOption = 
            {
                        anchor:"LeftMiddle",
                            endpoint:["Dot", {radius:3}],
                            paintStyle:{fillStyle:"#FFEF00"},
                paintStyle:{ fillStyle:sourceColor},
                isSource:false,
                isTarget:true,
                maxConnections:-1
            }

                    jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.node'), sourceOption);
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.node'), targetOption);
                        jsPlumb.draggable($('.node'));
                    });
                    </script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

In the above example, I want to connect Name--->Name2 , Age-->Age2 and DOB-->DOB2. 
Is it possible in jsPlumb or else is there any jquery/javascript plugin to do this operation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far!!!are you sure you dont want some php..
This is not sufficient information.Be more elaborative and put up your question in proper format!!!Time for some Edit

Comment: i have do it html and not in php. Till now i have created 2 tables and i am connecting those 2 table using addEndPoint() using jsplumb plug-in. Now i want each row from table_1 has to connect to each row of another table table_2. For example consider table_1 has 3 rows and table_2 also has 3 rows.

Comment: Post your code by editing the question!!!How will people come to know what actually is happening inside your code.If you are new to stackoverflow,then spend some time on meta stackOverflow and understand how to ask questions.You will definately get more responses to it!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong I think you are trying to make nodes of type "class" inside nodes of type "node". It seems like not possible.